# Header includes in implementation file is causing errors in Qt moc

Tags: c++, qt

Imagine I have a class `foo` with a header and an implementation file.

I also have those for `bar`. However, in `bar` I have an instance of `foo`. But I don't include `foo` in the header of `bar` but in the implementation file.

Qt's moc does not include the `foo` header, causing errors for not knowing the existence of the class `foo`.

Is there a way of keeping the include in the implementation file and having the moc add those includes as well?

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
```

**foo.h**

```
#pragma once

class foo {};
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
```

**bar.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtCore>

class bar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    foo instanceOfFoo;
};
```

The moc will not include foo.h.
Which in turn generates errors telling me moc_bar.cpp is unaware of a class named foo.

Comment: Why not have `#include "foo.h"` in `bar.h`?  Otherwise what is the real purpose of `bar.h` since it obviously requires the type `foo` to be fully defined?

Comment: The principle of keeping includes out of header files because of hidden dependencies, no other reason really.

Comment: You can't, it has nothing to do with Qt. `bar` has a `foo` member, it must know what `foo` is. You have to include foo.h. You could get around it by using a pointer instead and use a forward declaration, but IMHO, it's not the way to go.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks! Might wanna post it as an answer so I can close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: No, you can't.

The reason is that `bar` has a `foo` member. In order to generate the definition of `bar`, the compiler must know what a `foo` is. Otherwise the memory layout of `bar` would be impossible to determine.

So you have to `#include "foo.h"` in *bar.h*.

You could circumvent it by using a pointer to `foo` and a forward declaration but it sounds wrong to me.

Also:

> *"The principle of keeping includes out of header files [...]"*

There is no issue to have `#include` directives in header files. You only need to include what's necessary for your class to be completely defined *(e.g. You need a `std::string` member ? Just `#include <string>`)*.